# How to rewrite this code to use retrieve() method?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, kotlin, webclient

How to rewrite this code to use retrieve() method?

```
    suspend fun getEntity(): ResponseEntity<EntityDto> {
        return restClient
                .get()
                .uri { ... }
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .awaitExchange()
                .awaitEntity()
    }
```

When I use retrieve() I receive the following error:

> org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException:
> Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported for
> bodyType=org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity

Answer (score 0):

Your specified content type does not match with the content type in the response. Check the content type from the response and use appropriate one for `.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`. Also check if error has occurred during that call, so that whole expected response do not match because of the error.